The left-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must be of type 'any', an object type or a type parameter
I've been playing around with TypeScript (I'm still learning) and writing up a few test scenarios to better understand programming fundamentals.
export class Base {
    readonly id: string;

    constructor(id: string) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}


export class A extends Base {
    image: string;

    constructor(id: string, image: string) {
        super(id);
        this.image = image;
    }
}

export class B extends Base {
    occupancy: number;

    constructor(id: string, occupancy: number) {
        super(id);
        this.occupancy = occupancy;
    }
}

export class C extends Base {
    noiseLevel: string;

    constructor(id: string, noiseLevel: string) {
        super(id);
        this.noiseLevel = noiseLevel;
    }
}

function doSomething(param: A | B | C): string {
    if (param instanceof Base) {
        return 'base';
    } else if (param instanceof A) {
        return 'a';
    } else if (param instanceof B) {
        return 'b';
    } else if (param instanceof C) {
        return 'c';
    }
}

Say I tried the following:
doSomething(new A('idA', 'image');

doSomething(new B('idB', 1);

doSomething(new C('idC', 'high');

I would expect them to all return with the string 'base', because they are all subclasses of Base, and this was the first condition in the sequence to be checked.
I was OK with that, as I'm aware of polymorphism... but I wasn't able to even write the function. And the reason why is what's leaving me a bit confused.
When I hover over the word param for any of the else if's I get the error:
The left-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must be of type 'any', an object type, or a type parameter. ts(2358)
(parameter) param: never

I can't seem to find much about this online, at least nothing that really answers this for me.
Is it insinuating that Base is not a valid type? There isn't anything particularly wrong with Base itself, it's not something strange like an abstract class or anything like that (at least not at face value)... of course, it's being used as a superclass in our scenario, but the wording of the error makes it sound like the problem is with Base as a singularity. If the problem was with Base by itself, surely this error would have been flagged for the initial if too? But it isn't.
Hopefully, someone can help shine a bit of light on this. I'm finding it challenging as a beginner!
Thank you.
EDIT:
I wasn't very clear at the start, my apologies.
My compiler won't even let me write the function:
function doSomething(param: A | B | C): string {
    if (param instanceof Base) {
        return 'base';
    } else if (param instanceof A) {
        return 'a';
    } else if (param instanceof B) {
        return 'b';
    } else if (param instanceof C) {
        return 'c';
    }
}

Ergo, I was never even able to get as far as:
doSomething(new A('idA', 'image');

doSomething(new B('idB', 1);

doSomething(new C('idC', 'high');


param instanceof Base is always going to be true (try running console.log(doSomething(new A("","")))) so in the else statement param has been reduced to never. Essentially if you find yourself in that else block, TS thinks param is impossible and therefore you shouldn't check it with instanceof.  Remove the param instanceof Base test like this and it all works. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

sorry perhaps I wasn't clear - I am unable to even write the function doSomething... I have obviously shown it as written here, but I am getting squiggly lines in reality for the "else if (param" lines.. i'll edit my post accordingly - apologies. your help would still be appreciated!

"My compiler won't even let me write the function" ?? What happens, does it make the keyboard really hot or something? You can certainly write the function even if TypeScript complains, and it runs. TypeScript is warning you that there's no point in comparing param to anything in your else block because it is impossible. param has been reduced to never, as I linked above. I'm just repeating myself now, so I guess there's a communication barrier? Could you re-read my comments and see if it clicks? I'm not sure if I can rephrase it in a way that makes sense to you.

Your guess about there being a communication barrier is not the case, I appreciate your frustration but it isn't due to that. What you're saying is making sense to me, and what I meant was that it fails to compile. I thought the latter was obvious, no offence intended whatsoever.

I'm not offended, just not sure how to proceed. I explained the source of the errors on param instanceof A was that param has been reduced to never. Do you understand that and agree that's what's going on? If so I'll write up an actual answer with doc links. If not, do you think something is still missing?

Try param: Base | A | B | C, maybe the compiler is complaining since you are checking instanceof Base which it thinks applies only to the case where its checking for a pure Base instance and not A, B, or C. Basically, the typescript type system cannot a account for the niche behavior in javascript that instanceof the base class will return true.
Either way, I recommend being more explicit about type guards
like

class Base {
  name: "Base"
  constructor(){
    this.name="Base"
  }
  static is(value: unknown): value is Base{
    return value instanceof Base
  }
  static isLike(value: unknown): value is Base | BaseData {
    return typeof value === "object" && value !== null && (value as BaseData).name==="Base"
  }
  static from(obj: Base | BaseData){
    if(Base.is(obj)){
      return obj
    }
    else {
      // specific to your class and its constructor
      return new Base(...specific code...)
    }
  }
  toObject(): BaseData {
    return Object.assign({},this)
  }
}

type BaseData = {
  [K in keyof Base]: Base[K]
}


